# How to make a nested folder of a subdomain subfolder the web root using .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I'm trying to make a nested folder of a subdomain subfolder the web root in order for a test application to work properly.

**My current attempt using .htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.example.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.test.example.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !myapp/views/
RewriteRule (.*) /myapp/views/$1 [L]
```

**Preferred outcome**: when I visit `test.example.com/myapp/` it should show the content in the views folder. Is there a possibility of this working? I know this would work on the root domain but I need it to be working on the subdomain subfolder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove check for `HTTP_HOST` to allow this rule to execute for all the domains. More importantly you will need rules in site root and `myapp/` sub directories.

Code in site root:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !^myapp/views/ myapp/views%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Code in `myapp/.htaccess`:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !^views/ views%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```